# Не проходит авторизация(php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'kut', '', 'lic');
if(!isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['username']));
    $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password']));
    if(!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password)) {
      $query = "SELECT `user_id` , `username` FROM `signup` WHERE username = '$user_username' AND password = SHA('$user_password')";
      $data = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
        setcookie('user_id', $row['user_id'], time() + (60*60*24*30));
        setcookie('username', $row['username'], time() + (60*60*24*30));
        $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        header('Location: '. $home_url);
      }
      else {
        echo 'Извините, вы должны ввести правильные имя пользователя и пароль';
      }
    }
    else {
      echo 'Извините вы должны заполнить поля правильно';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

После ввода верного пароля и логина пользователя(в любом случае), просто вылазит - 'Извините, вы должны ввести правильные имя пользователя и пароль'. Как это решить?

Comment: Эх, ностальгия! Сколько форумов было "взломано" в 90-е благодаря такой "авторизации". подставляешь у себя в куки ид любого юзера - и вперёд

Comment: Если перевести на русский, то начало Вашего кода читается как: Подключение к базе. Если нет файла куки, то появляется ошибка. Если нет в массиве $_POST значения с именем submit...
В форме указано имя для submit? Верно?

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего у вас не проходит подключение к базе, проверьте что оно происходит, у вас $user_username и $user_password равны null.

P.S. воспользуйтесь механизмом сессий, у вас небезопасный код, вбейте в гугл/яндекс "php сессии авторизация пример"

Comment: Этот ответ противоречит условиям, описанным в вопросе.

Comment: В чем он противоречит ? в посткриптуме ? в ответе указана вполне конкретная причина почему код не работает и указано как сделать правильнее.

Comment: Если она не верна - следовательно вы знаете причину, раз знаете причину - тогда почему тут нет правильного ответа ? 

Вот придет автор вопроса и сможет прояснить ситуацию, или вы автор и сидите под двумя аккаунтами ?

Comment: Обратите внимание, мой ответ может помочь автору, ваши комментарии не несут вообще никакой практической пользы, несмотря на ваше знание нескольких причин, только оффтопик развели.